# python statsmodels.formula.api.ols: ValueError: For numerical factors, num_columns must be an int

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to reproduce the example from the help string of `statsmodels.api.anova_lm`:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

moore = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("Moore", "car",
                                 cache=True) # load data
data = moore.data
data = data.rename(columns={"partner.status" :
                            "partner_status"}) # make name pythonic
moore_lm = ols('conformity ~ C(fcategory, Sum)*C(partner_status, Sum)',
                data=data).fit()

table = sm.stats.anova_lm(moore_lm, typ=2) # Type 2 ANOVA DataFrame
print table
```

however, I get the following error message from `moore_lm = ols('conformity ~ C(fcategory, Sum)*C(partner_status, Sum)', data=data)`:

> ValueError: For numerical factors, num_columns must be an int

This is how data looks like:

```
>>> print data
      partner_status  conformity fcategory  fscore
0                low           8       low      37
1                ...         ...       ...     ...
```

I ran into the same problem with the data set I am actually interested in; so what causes this error?

On a side note, what does the `C(<column>, Sum)` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

update pasty:

```
 pip install https://github.com/pydata/patsy/archive/master.zip
```

in my case, it was from version 0.4 to '0.4.1+dev'

"C" represents categorical variables